# Automatic checking of GTM Tags

Tags: google-analytics, code-snippets, google-tag-manager

Is there is a tool or a solution that automatically checks if the GTM (Google Tag Manager) tags are working properly on a page?

I don't need it to do anything else except retrieve the bag of tags and let me know which any URLs where there is a problem with a tag.

I can only find manual validation checking and I would need to implement a solution for a large number of tags so automation would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few paid services that I can think of:

- [Observepoint](http://www.observepoint.com/)
- [Tag Inspector](https://taginspector.com/wp/front-page/)

I'm sure there are others, but those are the ones I've used.

You can also use GTM's error tracking to log client-side JS error. Doesn't really check to see what tags are firing, but will let you know when your JavaScript is having problems.

Good blog post here: [Using Google Tag Manager to log JavaScript errors in Google Analytics](http://dan-russell.com/2014/03/using-google-tag-manager-to-log-javascript-errors-in-google-analytics/)